# Displaying dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I create a program that add element into an array dynamically. Since user enter value the size of the array is increasing by one. I want to use array and not std::vector. I understand that in order to do what I want I have to copy the precedent array into a new array with the new size, it is wat I do, but when I want to display my array I get a runtime error. Moreover I don't understand where to place the delete[] ( in main, or in function). So if you can explain it will be graceful.

Thanks

This is my code

```
  #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void displayArray(int* data, int length)
{
    if (length)
    {
        cout << "Your array is containing: " << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            cout << *(data + i) << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Empty array" << endl;
    }
    
}
void resize(int* data, int length)
{
    int* temp = new int[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
    {
        *(temp + i) = *(data + i);
    }
    temp = data;
}
void insertArray(int* data, int length, int number)
{
    if (length != 1)
    {
        *(data + length - 1) = number;
    }
    else
    {
        *(data) = number;
    }

}
int main()
{
    int choice = 0, length = 0, value = 0;

    int* data = new int[length];


    do
    {
        cout << endl << "Choose an option:" << endl;
        cout << "1.Insert" << endl;
        cout << "2.Display" << endl;
        cout << "3.Exit" << endl;
        cin >> choice;
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "Insert a new value in array: " << endl;
            cin >> value;
            length++;
            resize(data, length);
            insertArray(data, length, value);
            break;
        case 2:
            displayArray(data, length);
            break;
        }
    } while (choice!=3);




    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The bug is here: `int size = 0; int* data = new int[size];` You allocated an array of size 0. You can put 0 items in it. Maybe instead allocate the array after asking the user how many items. and use the size entered by the user after some validation to make sure they entered a valid number and not -1 or frog or something invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t use `size` at all (as of now, you are creating an array of size 0 hence), I guess you take that input in your `choice` variable:

```
cin >> choice;
int* data = new int[choice];
```

Also, you should free the dynamically allocated memory on heap when done:

```
delete[] data;
return 0;
```